# XMLHttpRequest throwing csrf error response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make an XMLHttpRequest. My request fails with 403(forbidden) error saying

```
detail:"CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - Referer is insecure while host is secure."
```

This is how I am making the request. My Token is correct.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = true;

            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    console.log(this.response);
                    console.log("success")
                    //that.afterFaceAdded(response.id);
                }
            });

            xhr.open("PUT", url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");


            xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: It means the server won't let your HTTP page make an authenticated CORS request to it. You must serve your page and script over HTTPS.

Comment: But an ajax request works. Why is that?

Comment: Wait. The above code *is* an "ajax" request and you say you're getting an HTTP error from the server. So which is it ? works or not ?